# Angular 4 Google map integration issue

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript

I am trying to integrate the google map to the angular project. Where the lat-lng information is getting injected to the iframe URL. But It's not displaying the map and not showing any error in the console as well.

This is the template source,

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizeUrl('https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='+address?.latitude+','+address?.longitude+'&key=my_key')" width="393" height="165" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is angular code,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leftblock',
  templateUrl: './leftblock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leftblock.component.scss']
})
export class AppLeftblockComponent {

  address: any;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer

    this.address = {
        'latitude': '19.0759837'
        'latitude': '72.87765590000004'
    };

  ) { }

  sanitizeUrl(url) {
    console.log(url);
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First try with following.

In constructor use **this.address** also

```
constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { 
      this.address = [
        'latitude' => '19.0759837'
        'latitude' => '72.87765590000004'
    ];
}


sanitizeUrl() {
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='+this.address.latitude+','+this.address.longitude+'&key=my_key';
    console.log(url);
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <iframe [src]="sanitizeUrl('https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='+address.latitude+','+address.longitude+'&key=my_key')" width="393" height="165" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

you pass `longitude` in your frame but in your address array you declare 
`latitude` two time that's issue.

so you address obj should be like in component

```
  address = {'latitude': '19.0759837', 'longitude': '72.87765590000004'};
```

**also,**

you can also use angular package [ngui-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/map) instated of iframe. package integration easy and simple.

Comment: I am trying to use less third party packages to keep the vendor bundle js file size smaller.